# Why is it impossible to get a Tk `StringVar` in a unittest of code when that code has no trouble setting and getting the `StringVar`?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I want to write a unittest that needs to read a tkinter `StringVar`. I haven't got very far. The unittest looks like this:

```
def test_show_headers(self):
    cell = common.winfo_path(self.FIRST_CELL, self.table)
    print(cell)
    # cell.setvar(cell['textvariable'], 'hello mum')
    print(cell.getvar(cell['textvariable']))
```

The output looks like this:

```
.table outer frame.scrolled canvas.table frame.r0c0

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Stephenff\Programming\Study\Scratch\test_table_display.py", line 249, in test_show_headers
    print(cell.getvar(cell['textvariable']))
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 502, in getvar
    return self.tk.getvar(name)
_tkinter.TclError: can't read "PY_VAR0": no such variable
```

The first print statement confirms that I have the correct tkinter widget `(.table … .r0c0)` and the error shows that the widget has the correct `StringVar` identifier `"PY_VAR0"` although it identifies nothing.

If I uncomment the `setvar` line, the output changes to:

```
.table outer frame.scrolled canvas.table frame.r0c0
hello mum
```

It seems clear that the value identified by `"PY_VAR0"` has got lost somewhere. What is puzzling me is that `getvar` is successfully used in the code under test to create a callback. A simplified version of that code looks like this:

```
def _make_cell(self, parent, row_id, column_ix, cell_text):

    tk_string = tk.StringVar()
    cell = ttk.Entry(parent, name=self.cell_name(row_id, column_ix),
                     textvariable=tk_string)
    cell.setvar(cell['textvariable'], cell_text)
    cell.grid(row=row_id, column=column_ix)
    cell.bind('<Return>',
              (lambda event: self._cell_callback(
                  event, self.CellClicked(row_id, self.headers[column_ix]),
                  cell.getvar(cell['textvariable']))))

def _cell_callback(self, event=None, location=None, text=None):
    self.cell_clicked = location
    self.cell_text = text
    self.parent.focus_set()
    self.destroy()
```

This is a prototype and it has been thoroughly tested. The callback is working which means the identical `getvar` statement in the `_make_cell` method is functioning correctly. The code under test and its unittests are in different modules.

I found `setvar` and `getvar` in [Russell Owen's notes ('Getting Information from Widgets')](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/TkinterSummary.html). I am aware that neither `setvar` nor `getvar` are mentioned in Lundh or Shipman although they are in the [TckTk man](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/SetVar.htm) pages. That states the namespaces for variables are controlled by the flags argument. I don't know Tcl well enough to know if this could be the cause of my problem.

**Update 1**

The test provided correct results after I noticed that the first two lines of the code under test could be refactored from:

```
tk_string = tk.StringVar()
cell = ttk.Entry(parent, name=self.cell_name(row_id, column_ix),
                 textvariable=tk_string)
```

to:

```
cell = ttk.Entry(parent, name=self.cell_name(row_id, column_ix),
                 textvariable=tk.StringVar())
```

after which the unittest `test_show_headers` produces the correct output of:

```
.table outer frame.scrolled canvas.table frame.r0c0
Date
```

However, the refactoring should not be capable of producing this change. How is this possible and why does the original code cause Tk's `StringVar` to get lost?

**Update 2**

Threads are not used anywhere in this program.

The class I am testing is a subclass of ttk.Frame and it relies on an externally provided root window. For testing the root window is supplied by the unittest `setUp` method and removed in the `tearDown` method.

```
def setUp(self, withdraw=True):
    self.parent = tk.Tk()
    if withdraw:
        self.parent.withdraw()

def tearDown(self):
    self.parent.update()
    self.parent.destroy()
```

There are three test fixtures which are subclassed from a common base which contains the `setUp` and `tearDown`. I have confirmed that all three actually invoke the `tearDown`. As far as I'm able to tell by reading the code there is only one instance of the tcl/tk interpreter running.

Comment: is it possible that the unit test is either running in a separate thread, or has it's own root window (read: it's own internal tcl/tk interpreter)?

Comment: I've investigated your helpful suggestion and I've added some extra information to my original question. I'd feel more comfortable about this if I knew of a way of counting the actual number of active tcl/tk interpreters. Do you know if it's possible? (Come to think of it, this would be a valuable tool to guard against side effects in every tkinter test)

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, though the simple way to answer it is to ask "how many times do you instantiate the `Tk` class?". Each time you do, you get a new interpreter. If you create a widget without creating a root window first, a root window (and interpreter) is created for you. If you do that, and then create your own root window, you now have two.

Comment: I've refactored the test code to remove every test but one. That instantiates `Tk` once and destroys it too. The code under test is entirely controlled from the unittest. It does not contain any instantiation of `Tk`. Widgets are created there but can only be within the unittest's instance of `Tk`. 
If a second instance of `Tk` were the problem the refactoring I describe in 'Update 1' would have the effect of changing the instance of `Tk` in which the `StringVar` is created. In other words, the StringVar is created in the wrong instance until the refactoring creates it in the correct instance.